# simple command line stock control

Tags: java

I want to develop a command line solution for a supermarket to calculate the total of the customer's purchase and display it and after every customer's purchase the initial stock of all the items must be updated.(I've used only 3 items).But it's only calculating the total not updating the stock.(And I need to do it by using while loops & for loops only

```
import java.util.*;
public class newClass {
   public static void main(String args[]){
int qty1=100;
int qty2=200;
int qty3=300;

float price1=50.0f;
float price2=50.0f;
float price3=100.0f;

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Input item1 quantity");
int no1=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Input item2 quantity");
int no2=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println("Input item3 quantity");
int no3=sc.nextInt();
float total=(no1*price1)+(no2*price2)+(no3*price3);
while(qty1>=no1 & qty2>=no2 & qty3>=no3 )
{
    qty1=qty1-no1;
    qty2=qty2-no2;
    qty3=qty3-no3;
}
System.out.println("your total is="+total);
   } 

}
```

Comment: Have you used `&` in your code or '&&' ?. I guess you intend to use `&&`

Comment: How do you know it's not updating the stock? You don't print anything but the total. And why do you think you need t loop to subtract a number from a quantity?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of issue with your code. Firstly you intend to loop based on the in-house initial quantity but are not looping it on it. After updating quantity, you need to ask input from the user again if you have given quantity. You are not closing the `Scanner` object properly.

Below is modified version of your code. Hope this helps

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int qty1 = 100;
    int qty2 = 200;
    int qty3 = 300;

    float price1 = 50.0f;
    float price2 = 50.0f;
    float price3 = 100.0f;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (qty1 > 0 && qty2 > 0 && qty3 > 0) {  // You any of the quantity is out of stock, exit loop
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Stock: qty1: " + qty1 + " qty2: " + qty2 + " qty3: " + qty3 + "\n");
        System.out.println("Input item1 quantity");
        int no1 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input item2 quantity");
        int no2 = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Input item3 quantity");
        int no3 = sc.nextInt();
        if (qty1 < no1) { // making sure that asked quantity is not more that in-house quantity
            no1 = qty1;
        }
        if (qty2 < no2) {
            no2 = qty2;
        }
        if (qty3 < no3) {
            no3 = qty3;
        }
        qty1 = qty1 - no1;
        qty2 = qty2 - no2;
        qty3 = qty3 - no3;
        float total = (no1 * price1) + (no2 * price2) + (no3 * price3);

        System.out.println("your total is=" + total);
    }
    sc.close();
}
```